# Segue not firing from custom tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, segue

I'm experiencing what I'm sure is a beginner's mistake. I have a TableViewController that should segue to a second TableViewController upon selection of a custom cell.

I've segued to a UIViewController from a custom cell in the past but I can't figure out for the life of me why this segue isn't firing. Here's the code for the entire controller that should be firing the segue. Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit

class SourcesViewController: UITableViewController {

var sources: [Source] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem .setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sources.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_01", for: indexPath) as? SourceCell

        else {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_01", for: indexPath)
    }

    let currentSource = sources[indexPath.row]

    cell.sourceLabel.text = currentSource.name

    return cell
}




// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let sourceToSend = sources[indexPath.row]
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ArticlesViewController {
            destination.source = sourceToSend
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your segue doesn't get called because you are not invoking it. UIViewController has [perfromSegue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) method that you should use for that purpose.

From what I see you would want to perform the segue after tapping the cell. To achieve this add UITableViewDelegate method and perform segue from there:

```
/// - SeeAlso: UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "your_identifier_from_the_storyboard", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be on the right track. I've added the suggested code and a breakpoint reveals the call is being hit but there's still no segue. Please bear with me. I'm new to tableViews.

I also threw a console print command in the destination view controller that isn't firing so I'm fairly confident that the segue still isn't firing.

Comment: Instead of this, you can also try creating the whole thing in the storyboard. You can create segue directly from your cell to the new controller and it will do exactly the same thing that `didSelectRowAt` method does.

Comment: I've tried both methods and the segue appears to be firing but the destination view is still failing to load. :-/